# ¿Cómo generar números aleatorios en C++ de más de 7 cifras?

Tags: c++, random

Se como usar la función `srand()` y `rand()` para generar números aleatorios, el problema es que esos números están limitados a 5 cifras cuando mucho y necesito generar números de 7 u 8 dígitos. Leyendo un poco me encuentro que `RAND_MAX` tiene el valor máximo que puedo generar y al imprimirlo en consola es 32767. 
En otras fuentes dicen que el valor de `RAND_MAX` debería de ser de miles de millones por lo que no se en que creer.

¿Alguna idea de como generar números mas grandes?

Se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: has intentado algo como `int num = (rand() << 16) + rand();`? solo se me ocurre eso, no manejo c++  :P

Comment: Usa rand() para 7 números de una cifra, y luego los juntas ;)

Comment: ya habia pensado en eso, el problema es que voy a crear arreglos de hasta un millon de elementos y necesito tener la mayor variedad de números desde una cifra hasta hasta 7.

Answer (score 6):

En tu caso nos encontramos con dos problemas.

#### Limitaciones de `rand`.

La función [`std::rand`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) (y por extensión, todas las relacionadas como [`std::srand`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) se basan en el motor de generación de números pseudo-aleatorios de C. De hecho ambas funciones son una función de C adaptada a C++.

El tipo de retorno de `std::rand` es un `int`, así que el rango de números que puede devolver pertenecen al rango de `int`, cuyo [rango depende de la plataforma](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values):

- En sistemas de 16 bits, la cantidad de números almacenables por int es 2<sup>16</sup>:

  - 65.535 valores.
- En sistemas de 32 bits, la cantidad de números almacenables por int es 2<sup>32</sup>:

  - 4.294.967.295 valores.
- En sistemas de 64 bits, la cantidad de números almacenables por int es 2<sup>64</sup>:

  - 18.446.744.073.709.551.615 valores.

Como puedes ver, salvo que el entero sea de 16 bits podrás obtener números de 7 cifras sin problemas.

> #### Leyendo un poco me encuentro que `RAND_MAX` tiene el valor máximo que puedo generar y al imprimirlo en consola es 32767.

Ese es el valor máximo positivo del entero con signo en una plataforma de 16 bits. Dado que es con signo, la mitad de los valores se reservan para números negativos y la otra para positivos.

Así que, aparentemente estás trabajando en una plataforma de 16 bits.

#### Propuestas.

**C++11**

Usa la [cabecera de números pseudo-aleatorios](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) de C++11 [`<random>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) (no la de C, parte de [`<cstdlib>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib)):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    // Siempre 7 cifras
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1000000, 9999999);

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lSaJoPbobkaZFEFQ).

**Usa una cadena/arreglo de caracteres**

Si tu compilador de 16 bits no soporta C++11 va a ser complicado obtener números de más de 5 cifras, pero puedes *hacer trampas* y usar cadenas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void numero_de_7_cifras(char (&numero)[8])
{
    for (int indice = 0; indice != 7; ++indice)
    {
        numero[indice] = '0' + std::rand() % 10;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char numero[8] = {};

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        numero_de_7_cifras(numero);
        std::cout << numero << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WYc2wGzTKzUutPAC).

El problema de esta aproximación es que algunos dígitos tienen una ligera posibilidad de aparecer más a menudo y que a veces el número puede empezar por `0`, pero ya dejo a tu criterio si eso te es indiferente.

---

> #### Intenté usar la biblioteca de C++ `<random>` pero codeblocks no la reconoce.

La cabecera [`<random>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) pertenece al estándar de C++ de 2011, conocido como C++11. Si tu compilador no da soporte al estándar C++11 (o superior) no dispondrás de dicha cabecera.

[Code::Blocks](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) es el [IDE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado) que estás usando, no el compilador. Normalmente el IDE instala un compilador y el compilador instalado pone a disposición del usuario sus librerías.

Si tu IDE es reciente debería haber instalado un compilador con las librerías de C++11; puede que sea necesario indicar que quieres usar el estándar C++11 en los parámetros que se le pasan al compilador, el parámetro exacto dependerá del compilador que estés usando (pero podría ser `-std=c++11`).

> #### Mi sistema es de 64 bits, [...] ¿alguna idea de por qué se comporta como si fuera de 16?

Creo que mi respuesta inicial puede haber dado lugar a confusión. Por un lado el sistema puede ser de 16, 32 o 64 bits, pero por otro el compilador (si puede y es configurado adecuadamente) puede compilar para sistemas de 16, 32 o 64 bits. Si tu `RAND_MAX` tiene un valor de `32767` puede ser porque el compilador sólo pueda compilar a 16 bits o porque esté configurado para compilar a 16 bits, apuesto a que es lo segundo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu propuesta, ya intente usar la biblioteca de c++ <random> pero codeblocks no la reconoce, parece que la tendré que instalar manual y no se de donde descargarla, la segunda forma si que funcionaria pero como tendré arreglos de hasta un millón de elementos me interesa tener una variedad desde números de una cifra hasta de 7.

Comment: Solo una cosa mas, mi sistema es de 64 bits, de eso estoy muy seguro, entonces alguna idea de porque se comporte como si fuera de 16 ? Estoy usanso un IDE, codeblocks y el compilador parece ser GNU GCC Compiler.