# ¿De que sirve srand(GetTickCount())?

Tags: c++

Veo muchas veces en diferentes códigos esta funcion,

```
srand(GetTickCount())
```

¿Para que realmente se utiliza?

Comment: Hola Smith. ¿Qué funcion dices: `srand` o `GetTickCount()`?¿Has leido la documentacion? Qué dudas concretas tienes?  Mira [ask] y [help/on-topic] para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Seguro que es C++? No me suenan esas funciones.

Comment: Sería bueno que incluyas una porción del código donde encuentras dichas funciones. Asimismo, GetTickCount tiene pinta de ser más un método de C# que de C++.

Comment: El srand en c++ por mi experiencia mediana en c++ se usa con la libreria time.h y sirve para funciones aleatorias que alguien me corrija si me estoy equivocando saludos !

Comment: @Xam es C++ bajo Windows. [enlace a GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `srand` es una función que inicializa el generador de números aleatorios.
- `GetTickCount` es una función específica de Windows (accesible únicamente a través de su API), que te devuele el número de milisegundos desde que se inició el equipo por última vez.

Estas dos funciones en conjunto, lo que pretenden, es proporcionar una semilla inicial aleatoria para que el ciertas partes del programa presenten una funcionalidad impredecible (por ejemplo repartir cartas, elegir una serie de números al azar, ...).

Ahora bien, como bien ha destacad @Paula_plus_plus en numerosas ocasiones ([un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53235/463)), desde C++11 existen mecanismos mucho más *aleatorios* y seguros que `srand`, que pasa a ser una opción poco recomendable.